# DB link in postgres looking at another localhost image : relation tablename does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, dblink

i'm using docker to host two different postgresql instances to try and produce a proof of concept for python as an etl to move data between the two i can connect to the one via python fine but then when calling a procedure inside the first instance it cant find the table in the second instance im connecting to the second instance using dblink using this code

```
FROM dblink('host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres password=postgres dbname=postgres','SELECT * FROM staging.test')
```

the error message from this is that the relation staging.test does not exist

Comment: You are probably connecting to the wrong database.

Comment: i connect to port 5431 to call the procedure that contains the line above which connects to the port with the DB on that im trying to copy the data from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using multiple docker images with postgresql installed on each to get these images to talk to each other when on local host in the connection string use the service name instead of local host

```
FROM dblink('host=ServiceName port=5432 user=postgres password=postgres dbname=postgres',
            'SELECT * FROM staging.test')
```